# how to get the next word of a specified word in string

Tags: string, bash

I searched here and there a but i couldn't find any appropriate answer to my question. but i apologize if it is already answered.

I have a bash script that connects to different oracle databases to perform different operational tasks. The problem is I want to hash my password's and store them beside users in a string like this

```
DBAUTH="user1 user1password user2 user2password ... userN userNpassword"
```

I need a function to get the username and return the password to me ( the next word )

With regards.

Comment: Why not use an associative array where the username is the index?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a string, use an associative array:

```
DBAUTH=([user1]=user1password [user2]=user2password ... [userN]=userNpassword)
```

Then you can use `${DBAUTH[$user]}` to get the password for a username.

Comment: Thank you very much on our solution. didn't know about the associative array. Very useful. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

*This worked for me:*

```
#!/bin/bash

DBAUTH="user1 user1password user2 user2password userN userNpassword"

function getpass () {
    user="$1"
    # Skip invalid users
    if ! grep -wq "$user" <<< "$DBAUTH" ; then return; fi
    # Extract the password
    echo "$DBAUTH" | sed -r "s/.*$user ([^ ]*).*/\1/"
}
```

*Run result:*

```
getpass user1
user1password
...
getpass user2
user2password
... 
getpass user_invalid
# nothing printed
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line with awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="user1"
file="filepath"

awk -F"\"" '{ print $2 }' $file | awk -v username="$user" -F" " '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i == username ) print $(i+1); }'
```

This outputs:

> user1password